# Spinner didnt update

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    String dateData;
    int choice ;
    public HashSet<String> keyList = new HashSet<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> temperatures = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> atList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList dataList=new ArrayList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,new SwipeGestureDetector());
        Spinner toList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toList);
        toList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
//      toList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }
    ........................
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
            Dialog.dismiss();

            Iterator<String> iter = keyList.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                String key =iter.next();
                dataAdapter.add(key);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    ......................
```

..............................................................................

Sorry for this silly question , but i hav been doing it again and again from 0. it still doesn't get what i want. WHat problem i having now is bout the spinner didn't update itself after i set dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Before this it work but my table isn't working .
now my table is working, this spinner not working. Omg 
really need help desperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to add `toList.setAdapter(dataAdapter)` before initialize `dataAdapter`.So set `dataAdapter` after  getting data in it,i.e. change

```
        toList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
//      toList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

to

```
       dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        toList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
//      toList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Comment: Omg got ~ @Giru Bhai . you are such savior  ~ thanks ~ i can't see the mistakes there ~ thanks again ~